# IIS 7.5 Configuration - Idle Time-out and Recycling Interval & Precompile

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

Let me preface this by saying I am in no way shape or form a server admin.

I have a site that I've inherited that runs as a web app. The site is very busy during normal business hours then slows down to a trickle for the rest of the day. Every morning the first users that hit the site are getting very long load times because IIS has gone idle. The site runs on 5 load balanced web IIS instances and unfortunately the site takes well over a minute to recompile, which leads to users complaining the site is unresponsive and slow.

I have been thinking about changing the idle time-out to 0 to see if that will alleviate the problem. If I suggest this change, are there any known issues I am opening myself up to? I have found a lot of info online but nothing definitive, stating the recommended settings.

On a sort of related note, when ever a code drop is done and the app pool is recycled, and a compile is done. Would a precompile take care of this issue as well?

Thanks,
Duane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Application Initialization Module for IIS 7.5](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization)

> “…IIS Application Warm-Up for IIS 7.5 enables IT Professionals to
>   improve the responsiveness of their Web sites by loading the Web
>   applications before the first request arrives…”

[Keep your ASP.Net websites warm and fast 24/7](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/05/06/keep-your-aspnet-websites-warm-and-fast-247)